# How to create new column for a pandas dataframe based on gouping of a string column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['A','A','A','B','B'],
                    'b':['Alabama','Alabama','Antioch','Brisbane','Boolean']})
```

I want to add two new columns say 'n1' and 'n2' so that all rows belonging to first group of column 'a' will have value 1 and next group will have value 2 in new column 'n1'. Same logic for column 'b' and 'n2' but nested within grouping of 'a'

The resulting dataframe should look like this (for some reason markdown table is not working hence a link):

[image]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) to *Encode input values as an enumerated type or categorical variable*; To get `n2` column, just group by `a` and factorize `b`:

```
import pandas as pd

df['n1'] = pd.factorize(df.a)[0] + 1
df['n2'] = df.groupby('a').b.transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0] + 1)

df
#   a          b    n1  n2
#0  A    Alabama    1   1
#1  A    Alabama    1   1
#2  A    Antioch    1   2
#3  B   Brisbane    2   1
#4  B    Boolean    2   2
```

Comment: Thank you sir! How did you get :

n2=1 for Brisbane and 2 for Boolean?

I get n2=2 for Brisbane and 1 for Boolean

Comment: I tried again and it worked exactly as your results show

Comment: on another try I get n2=2 for Brisbane and 1 for Boolean again.

Comment: The result of `pd.factorize` depends on the order of elements in the original data. Do you need the number to be in a specific order?

Comment: I am creating df exactly the same way i.e. 

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['A','A','A','B','B'],
                    'b':['Alabama','Alabama','Antioch','Brisbane','Boolean']})

The order of elements is exactly the same. Just curious why the value of n2 varies for each test.

In this case it does not matter but in some specific requirement it could. Try a few times FYI...I did these tests in IDLE. I am not sure if I did

del df each time or not before creating the df

Answer (score 0):

Or using `astype` `category`

```
df['n1'] = df.a.astype('category').cat.codes.add(1)
df['n2'] = df.groupby('a').b.transform(lambda x: x.astype('category').cat.codes.add(1))

df
Out[1254]: 
   a         b  n1  n2
0  A   Alabama   1   1
1  A   Alabama   1   1
2  A   Antioch   1   2
3  B  Brisbane   2   2
4  B   Boolean   2   1
```

Comment: Thank you Wen. I like your answer too. But I can only accept one answer.

Comment: @ShirishRanade No worry nice day ~ :)